# Decrypt MySQL fields that were encrypted using Java

Tags: java, mysql, encryption, cryptography

I have some String fields that are being encrypted/encrypted using the following Java methods:

```
public class Encryptor {

    private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES";
    private static final byte[] keyValue =
            new byte[] { 'M', 'y', 'S', 'u', 'p', 'e', 'r', 'S',
            'e', 'c', 'r', 'e', 't', 'K', 'e', 'y' };

    public static String encrypt(String valueToEnc) throws Exception {
        Key key = generateKey();
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] encValue = cipher.doFinal(valueToEnc.getBytes());
        return new BASE64Encoder().encode(encValue);
    }

    public static String decrypt(String encryptedValue) throws Exception {
        Key key = generateKey();
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] decodedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedValue);
        byte[] decValue = cipher.doFinal(decodedValue);
        return new String(decValue);
    }

    private static Key generateKey() throws Exception {
        return new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, ALGORITHM);
    }
}
```

The methods are working as desired for both encrypting and decryption by calling the respective method.  I am persisting the encrypted Strings to a MySQL database.  I would like to occasionally decrypt the Strings while in the MySQL command line.  I've been trying to use

`SELECT AES_DECRPYT(encrypted_field, MySuperSecretKey), FROM table;`

However, this is returning a `null` results for all the fields in that column.  Am I able to decrypt AES encrypted fields in MySQL that weren't encrypted by MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the issue I was having was that I was forgetting about the `BASE64Encoder` that I was using to encrypt the Strings on the Java side.  I was able to get the correct data back with the following MySQL command:

`SELECT AES_DECRYPT(FROM_BASE64(encrypted_field), 'MySuperSecretKey') FROM table;`